# Could not download gradle.jar

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, google-fabric

I'm trying to run a react native project version 0.26
but currently when I tried to run "react-native run-android"
it take about 10 minutes then this building exception appeared:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
  >   Could not download gradle.jar (io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.23.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.23.0/gradle-1.23.0.jar'.
  >   Connection reset

I don't know what is the cause of this problem or how to solve this it, and couldn't find any helpful solution

Comment: `wget https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.23.0/gradle-1.23.0.jar` is ok for me. Any other connectivity issue ?

Comment: @ToYonos No, I don't think I have any issue in Internet connection

Comment: Thank you, restarting my router solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I also face the same issue.

Goto to Android Studio File->Settings->Build, Execution...->Gradle

set "Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)" and unchecked the "Offline work" and apply changes.